# Is this inconsequent python behaviour?

Tags: python, subclass, class-method, python-3.9, pathlib

So, i was looking at the pathlib source code and i noticed some os lib functions were incorperated into the pathlib classes. I must admit that it took me a little while to understand how this works.

```py
import os

class Foo:
    listdir = os.listdir
    join = os.path.join
    walk = os.walk

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __fspath__(self):
        return self.name

curr = Foo('.')
pipo = Foo('pipo')
```

This class definition adds the listdir, join and walk functions of the os library as methods on the Foo class. The Foo class is recognized as a PathLike object because it also has the `__fspath__` method.

When `curr.join('bar')` is called it will join the name of curr, '.', with 'bar'. The code below shows this exact behaviour, with results i would expect.

```sh
$ tree
.
├── pipo
│   └── clown
└── test.py

1 directory, 2 files
$
```

```py
>>> curr.join("baz") 
./baz
>>>
>>> pipo.join("baz")
pipo/baz
>>>
>>> [x for x in curr.walk()]
[('.', ['pipo'], ['test.py']), ('./pipo', [], ['clown'])]
>>>
>>> [x for x in pipo.walk()]
[('pipo', [], ['clown'])]
>>>
```

Then i tried the listdir function ... and it **failed**. The listdir function shows different behaviour and i'm stumped as to why?

```sh
>>>
>>> os.listdir()
['pipo', 'test.py']
>>>
>>> curr.listdir()
['pipo', 'test.py']
>>>
>>> os.listdir("pipo")
['clown']
>>>
>>> pipo.listdir()
['pipo', 'test.py']
>>>
```

The listdir method on pipo shows the same output as the listdir on curr?

It seems to me like `join` and `walk` accept the self reference but somehow `listdir` does not. Why would that be?

Comment: `os.listdir` is a built-in function, not just a library function. It doesn't bind the way a function written in Python does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `function` class implements the [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html), allowing `os.path.join` to act as an instance method.  `os.listdir` is not an instance of `function`; it's an instance of `builtin_function_or_method`, which does not implement the descriptor protocol.

`curr.join(...)` is equivalent to `Foo.join.__get__(curr, Foo)(...)`. `curr.listdir()` is equivalent to `Foo.listdir()`: `curr.listdir` does not exist, and `Foo.listdir` just calls `listdir`, not the non-existent `listdir.__get__` which would take care of passing `curr` as the implicit first argument.